# 15 puzzle with AStar Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, a-star

I've made a simple 15puzzle game using A-star algorithm with Manhattan Distance.
For easy problems it works, but the solution isn't the optimal one.

For example, if a movement is:

> Right->Up

my solution would be:

> Right->Up->Left->Down->Right->Up

If i have a hard game to solve, it takes infinite time and get no solution to problem, I think because of this problem.

To implement my game I have followed wikipedia pseudocode of A* algorithm.
Here is my AStar function:

```
public ArrayList<String> solution(Vector<Integer> start){

    ArrayList<String> movePath = new ArrayList<String>(); //Path to solution
    PriorityQueue<Node> closedQueue = new PriorityQueue<Node>(500,new Comparator<Node>() {
        @Override public int compare(Node a,Node b) {
            return a.get_fScore() - b.get_fScore();
        }
    });

    Node node = new Node(start,movePath,heuristic);
    int cnt =0;
    openQueue.add(node);

    while(!openQueue.isEmpty() ) {

        //Alt if it takes too much time (ToRemove)
        if(cnt == (150)*1000) {
            ArrayList<String> noResult = new ArrayList<String>();
            noResult.add("Timeout");
            return noResult;
        }

        Node bestNode = openQueue.remove(); //Remove best node from openQueue
        closedQueue.add(bestNode); //Insert its to closedQueue

        cnt++;
        if( cnt % 10000 == 0) {
            System.out.printf("Analizzo %,d posizioni. Queue Size = %,d\n", cnt, openQueue.size());
        }
        //Get first step from bestNode and add to movePath
        if(!bestNode.isEmptyMoves()) {
            String step = bestNode.get_moves().get(0);
            movePath.add(step);
        }
        //Exit Condition
        if(bestNode.get_hScore() == 0) {
            return bestNode.get_moves();
        }
        //Looking for childs
        Vector<Node> childs = get_nextMoves(bestNode);
        for(int i=0; i<childs.size(); i++) {

            if(closedQueue.contains(childs.elementAt(i))) 
                continue;

            childs.elementAt(i).set_gScore(bestNode.get_gScore()+1); //Increment level in tree

            if(!openQueue.contains(childs.elementAt(i)))
                openQueue.add(childs.elementAt(i));

            else {
                //!Never reached this level!
                System.out.println("Here!");
                //TODO Copy child from openQueue to closedQueue
            }

        }   
    }
    return null;
```

That is my function to find neighbours:

```
public Vector<Node> get_nextMoves(Node act){

    Vector<Node> steps = new Vector<Node>();
    int position = act.get_valuePos(0);
    String lastMove = act.get_lastMove();
    //System.out.println(lastMove);


    //Right Child
    if(position + 1 < 16 && position + 1!=3 && position + 1!=7 && position+1 !=11 && lastMove !="Left") {

        int temp_pos[] = copyToArray(act.get_posVect());//Copy array of positions of ACT to a temp_pos array
        temp_pos[position] = temp_pos[position+1]; //Switch 0 position with Right position
        temp_pos[position+1] = 0;

        ArrayList<String> temp_moves = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i=0; i<act.get_moves().size(); i++) {
            temp_moves.add(act.get_moves().get(i)); //Save old steps
        }
        temp_moves.add("Right");//And add new one

        Node child = new Node(temp_pos,temp_moves,act.get_heuristic()); //New Node
        steps.addElement(child);//Added to vector
    }
    //Left Child
    if(position - 1 >= 0 && position - 1 != 4 && position - 1 != 8 && position - 1 != 12 && lastMove !="Right") {
        int temp_pos[] = copyToArray(act.get_posVect());
        temp_pos[position] = temp_pos[position-1];
        temp_pos[position-1] = 0;

        ArrayList<String> temp_moves = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i=0; i<act.get_moves().size(); i++) {
            temp_moves.add(act.get_moves().get(i));
        }
        temp_moves.add("Left");

        Node child = new Node(temp_pos,temp_moves,act.get_heuristic());
        steps.addElement(child);
    }
    //Up Child
    if(position - 4 >= 0 && lastMove !="Down") {
        int temp_pos[] = copyToArray(act.get_posVect());
        temp_pos[position] = temp_pos[position-4];
        temp_pos[position-4] = 0;

        ArrayList<String> temp_moves = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i=0; i<act.get_moves().size(); i++) {
            temp_moves.add(act.get_moves().get(i));
        }
        temp_moves.add("Up");

        Node child = new Node(temp_pos,temp_moves,act.get_heuristic());
        steps.addElement(child);
    }
    //Down Child
    if(position + 4 < 16 && lastMove !="Up") {
        int temp_pos[] = copyToArray(act.get_posVect());
        temp_pos[position] = temp_pos[position+4];
        temp_pos[position+4] = 0;

        ArrayList<String> temp_moves = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i=0; i<act.get_moves().size(); i++) {
            temp_moves.add(act.get_moves().get(i));
        }
        temp_moves.add("Down");

        Node child = new Node(temp_pos,temp_moves,act.get_heuristic());
        steps.addElement(child);
    }
    return steps;
```

And that is my ManhattanDistance function:

```
public int calcolaDist(Vector<Integer> A) {
    int result = 0;
    Vector<Integer> goal_Mat = initialize_Mat();

    for(int i=0; i<16; i++) {
        int x_goal = (goal_Mat.indexOf(i))/4;
        int y_goal =  (goal_Mat.indexOf(i))%4;

        int x_def = (A.indexOf(i))/4;
        int y_def = (A.indexOf(i))%4;

        if(A.elementAt(i) > 0) {

            result += Math.abs(x_def - x_goal);
            result += Math.abs(y_def - y_goal);
        }
    }

    return result;
```

If my puzzle is:

> start = {1,3,0,4,5,2,7,8,9,6,10,11,13,14,15,12}

My solution will be:

> [Left, Down, Down, Right, Down, Right, Up, Left, Down, Right, Up, Left, Down, Right]

I know that using Vectors isn't a good choice and my code is "a little" dirty, but I'm going to clean its as soon as I get out of that problem!

Thank you all!

Comment: I will take a closer look later (haven't read your code) but I remember when I did this exact same puzzle: one problem that was causing it to loop infinitely was that I was adding the action that would return to the father node in the available actions, maybe this is it.

Comment: Here's a [helpful resource](https://algorithmsinsight.wordpress.com/graph-theory-2/a-star-in-general/implementing-a-star-to-solve-n-puzzle/) on A* and IDDFS for solving 15 puzzles. A* uses a lot of memory and will generally crash on 15 puzzles, so IDDFS or a pattern database is a good solution. I'd recommend a round of code cleanup on this post to produce an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with markers to identify your problem areas. If you want to eliminate the cycles you mention, you may need to keep track of all visited positions rather than only checking for cycles of length 1.

Comment: Thank you ggolern! This is a university homework so (unluckly) I can not use a pattern database. And yes, I will clean my code asap!!

Answer (score 0):

First, I see a bit of confusion in your code with the OPEN and CLOSED queues. The OPEN queue should be the one that manages the priority of the nodes (`PriorityQueue`). This is not needed for CLOSED, which only stores the visited nodes and their cost (maybe your algorithm will be more efficient changing CLOSED by a `HashSet` or `HashMap` to avoid ordering the nodes in CLOSED as well). I can't see in your code how you initialized the OPEN queue, but maybe that is one issue with your implementation of A*.

The other issue I see with your code is that with A*-based algorithms, you need to manage the situation in which you reach a node that is already in OPEN/CLOSED, but with a different cost. This can happen if you visit a node from different parents, or you enter in a loop. The algorithm will not work properly if you are not taking that into account.

1. If you visit a node that is already in the OPEN queue, and the new node has a lower f-score, you should remove the old node from OPEN and insert the one with the lower cost.
2. If the node has a higher cost (in OPEN or CLOSED) then you should simply discard that node to avoid loops.

The problem is though, but the state space is finite and the algorithm should finish at some point. I see that your implementation is in Java. Maybe it would be helpful for you if you take a look to the library [Hipster4j](https://hipser4j.org), which has [an implementation of A*](https://github.com/citiususc/hipster/blob/1.0.X/hipster-core/src/main/java/es/usc/citius/hipster/algorithm/AStar.java), and [an example solving the 8-puzzle](https://github.com/citiususc/hipster/blob/1.0.X/hipster-examples/src/main/java/es/usc/citius/hipster/examples/EightPuzzleProblemExample.java).

I hope my answer helps. Good luck!

Comment: Hello Adrian, thank you for help! First of all, yes, I don't need to use a PriorityQueue on CLOSED. I'm taking a look to the library, but I cant use it in my project because it is a university homework.
My initialization of OPEN is : `openQueue= new PriorityQueue<Node>(1000, new Comparator<Node>() {
   @Override public int compare(Node a,Node b) {
    return a.get_fScore() - b.get_fScore();
   }`

Comment: Maybe I'm a little confused about "how to find" a node inside the queue. I use the method `compare` to search its in CLOSED (if found, jump to next step and not add neighb. in OPEN), then use again `compare` to search in OPEN, if not found, add to OPEN. Else, i've not implemented yet what to do, i've just added a print, but it never reach this point.
Maybe I should search for nodes in queues in another way, so I can first search if the node has the same array of elements, and then i can compare their score. Could that work? Thank you again!

Comment: Yes, then the initialization of OPEN is correct! What we did in the library to find if a node is in the queues is to store two separated `Map<State, Node>`, one for OPEN and one for CLOSED. In this case the `State` would be your array with the numbers of the puzzle. And for OPEN we also use a `PriorityQueue` as you do. When we want to look for a `Node` in OPEN, we check if it is in the `Map`, given the `State`. Thus we can compare the costs of old nodes with the new ones. And if a Node in OPEN has to be re-inserted, we update the `Map`, remove the old one in the queue, and insert the new one.